# MySQL remote access via SSH Tunnel error

Tags: mysql, freebsd, ssh-tunnel

I've created an SSH tunnel on my local machine to reach an access to the mysql server on my remote machine. Everything is fine, tunnel is working if I get this error, but why this error occurs?

Here is the error message:

> *2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0*

It happends only, when I want to connect via Navicat (SSH Tunnel) from my local to the remote machine, on the remote machine mysql works without such errors.

Have you guys any solutions for that?

Comment: Same here, I've been trying to use HeidiSQL, MySQL Workbench, and NaviCat, and none of them allow me to connect to the server.

Comment: how did you create the ssh tunnel ? can you please post your command ?

Comment: @dom First way , is  putty: http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html (ofc. with different ports), second way I've tried is the SSH connection tunnel option in the Navicat Premium - in both cases I get the same errors.

Comment: @Cyclone have you tried it doing that way: http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html

Comment: @dom ... This is the same as this: http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html , result is the same too: `2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Comment: what value you have for bind-address in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: None, I've commented it since I dont want my MySQL to has port 3306 open, thats why I'm using the tunnel...

Comment: but you still have to listen on the local host port 3306 - try using 127.0.0.1 for the bind-adress. it will not allow external access - only from the machine you are running the sql server on.

Comment: @dom Thanks, it worked ;). You are welcome to answer this question so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when the configuration of the bind-adress option is wrong. Your MySQL server at least should listen on the localhost - 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Login to your local Linux machine then run this command:

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N user@remote.server.com
```

Use the mysql database from remote server:

```
mysql -u root -p --port 3307 -h 127.0.0.1
```

Make sure the local mysql does not use the same port in Linux environment.